# POJO Property change listener - Ideal way

Tags: java, while-loop, javabeans

I am developing a REST based web application, which will call a 3rd system asynchronously for some data (using websockets). So
Browser -> REST -> My WebApp -> Another App -> My WebApp -> Browser
The communication between My WebApp to Another APP is asynchronous and I can only track the responses for a request using some identifiers. 
So, I request C as `<counter>.C` and the response will be `<counter>.Response` where both counters will be same.

To map the response to request, I am setting the command, counter, flag to a bean. I keep a while loop which keeps on checking whether the flag has been set or not. Once I get the response, the set the flag, while loop exits and I know that the data is available.

Is this the right way? Is there a way I can make this better, because I feel (I might be wrong!) that keeping an open while loop is incorrect.

Class bean is set like below,

```
public void setAllProperties(){
 bean.setCommand(commandString);
 bean.setCounter(counter);
 bean.hasResponse(false);
}
```

The snippet in webservice is

```
bean.setAllProperties();
sendToApplication(bean);
int checkCounter = 0;
while(!bean.hasResponse && checkCounter > 0){
  if(bean.hasResponse){
     checkCounter++;
     // loggers and other logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: How is the "other app" able to update your bean class?

Comment: Well it is not updating the bean class, it is returning a response. Using websockets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop defeats a lot of the value of the asynchronous operation.  It also consumes a significant amount of CPU time (try adding a delay - a quick sleep - when using such a loop).

I recommend to use "wait()" and "notify()"/"notifyAll()" instead.

In the code that's waiting for a response, do something like this:

```
synchronized ( bean ) {
    while ( ! bean.hasResponse ) {
        bean.wait();
    }
}
```

In the code that processes the response and updates the bean:

```
synchronized ( bean ) {
    bean.hasResponse = true;
    bean.notifyAll();
}
```

Comment: This worked fine, I added a timeout as well into this just to ensure there are no threads waiting infinitely. Thanks. Sorry for the late response.